.Net service doesn't include soapenv:Header, anyway to include it manually?
I've got a WSDL service that looks like this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <authToken loggedin="YES" soapenv:actor="" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns="https://api.learningassistant.com" xmlns:ns1="https://api.learningassistant.com">
      <id type="xsd:string"> {ID} </id>
      <uuid type="xsd:string"> {UUID} </uuid>
    </authToken>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
....
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

I add the service to .Net but it doesn't send the authentication header, Is there any way to add it?
MyClient AuthClient = new MyClient();
MyClient.Method(arg1, arg2, ..)

MyClient.ClientCredentials doesn't seem to have anything to do with this custom header
App.Config
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyMethod.cfcSoapBinding" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="XXXX"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyMethod.cfcSoapBinding"
        contract="MyService.MyMethod" name="MyMethod.cfc" />
    </client>

Is there any workaround?
